# Sharing project folder in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I share a project/working directory between two Android Studio installation in two different computers? The shared repository is a file sharing cloud service like Dropbox.com or box.net.

The reason I want to do this is that I have a desktop and a laptop each with Android Studio. I want to be able to seamlessly do development work between the two systems without having to checkin or checkout code in a code repository.

I don't plan to run the two Android Studio concurrently. This is just for me - one user.

I used to be able to do this with Eclipse ADT but with Android Studio I am getting multiple errors - missing libraries, etc.

Any suggestions on this use case is also welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Ray

Comment: are both computers same OS? If you have different OS, it is tricky as your paths will be different. If same OS, then you may be able to do with minimal change.

Comment: Yes, both are running the same OS. It isn't as seamless as with ADT. When switching workstations I get missing libraries and multiple errors. What would be an ideal approach in this case? I'm sure this is not that uncommon - developers using multiple systems and opening up a shared folder project repository. Another option is a SVN checkin/checkout but I would like to avoid setting up a repository if possible. Thanks.

Comment: I use dropbox and use 2 computers. I make sure home directory are the same eg both are say "/Users/bond/". If not then I create an alias on one of the computer to match the path. So when the content is synced it should make no difference. Also  you usually AndroidStudio caches states so u might need to do clean project after you open. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working, to begin with. It was an oversight on my part. I needed to download the latest version of Android Studio (including the updates). Since applying updates I can open the project in another device by referencing the project working folder in the shared folder (in this case Box.net). I just get an initial prompt on the SDK location, that it is unable to find the original location. But it did offer to use the SDK location on the current computer.

When using the current device's SDK folder it will say that it will "modify the project's local.properties file." I click OK on this and it's all good.

This is what I wanted to do. But I'm looking at GitHub now. Thanks.